# menu share across multiple activities

Tags: java, android

I have multiple activities sharing the same options menu so in my every activity, I am doing

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:
           Intent opensettings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
           startActivity(opensettings);
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
          ...others

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to share the above code amongst different activities?

I have tried adding a class

```
class MenuHelper{
   Context ctx;
  public MenuHelper(Context context){
    ctx=context
  }

 public boolean openMenuItems(Menu item){
   switch(item.getItemId()) //here .getItemId() doesnt work{

      case R.id.settings: //R.id.settings not found

    }

  }

}
```

But am stuck in my helper class. How do I proceed so that in my different activities I only have to

```
MenuHelper menuitems = new MenuHelper(this);
menuitems.openMenuItems(menu)
```

Comment: Use a BaseActivity for all  .  Or Consider using `Fragment` instead of multiple Activities . Using `Fragment` will be a better approach.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question to the one it is being marked duplicate against.  Sharing code across activities and implementing a helper for use across activities are two different things.  Using the BaseActivity as suggested in the reference "already asked question" is also, at least IMHO, an anti-pattern, where the user is attempting to creating an object that can be used in composition and we're telling them instead to use inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `BaseActivity` where you can put the common implementation across your activities and then have other activities extend the `BaseActivity`

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Any other common methods

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
               Intent opensettings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
               startActivity(opensettings);
                return true;
            case R.id.help:
              ...others

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

You can now create your activities extending `BaseActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

}
```

Comment: should i add this Base activity to manifest?

Comment: No BaseActivity should not be added to the manifest

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a super class for your common Activities? If you create a super class, like so:

```
public class MySharedMenuActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { ... }
}
```

Then, if you extend that class for the activities you want, you will be able to access the shared menu.

Answer (score 1):

## Inheritance

As the other responses suggest, you could use inheritance to provide this sort of functionality. That does break the "favor composition over inheritance rule", but may be the practical solution for simple applications.

## Composition

I think you are on the right path with creating a "menu helper" of sorts. I'd prefer a name such as `OptionsMenuHandler` and would probably write it like this:

```
public class OptionsMenuHandler {

    private final Activity activity;

    public OptionsMenuHandler(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // do menu inflation here.
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent openSettings = new Intent(activity, SettingsActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(openSettings);
                return true;
            case R.id.help:
                // others
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // do menu preparation here.
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final OptionsMenuHandler optionsMenuHandler = new OptionsMenuHandler(this);

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return optionsMenuHandler.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) ||
                   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return optionsMenuHandler.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu) ||
                   super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return optionsMenuHandler.onOptionsItemSelected(item) ||
                   super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This does require extra boiler plate in each Activity.  It also creates abstraction.  The abstraction is justified because it keeps the code DRY.  I also like the fact that business logic isn't tucked away and invisible inside a parent class somewhere... the composition makes the location of the business logic a lot more obvious.

## Base Activity that Supports Composition

Another option would be to support composition in a base Activity as follows...

Create a well defined abstraction:

```
public interface OptionsMenuHandler {
    boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu);
    boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item);
    boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu);
}
```

Create an implementation for the abstraction:

```
public class DefaultOptionsMenuHandler implements OptionsMenuHandler {

    private final Activity activity;

    public DefaultOptionsMenuHandler(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // do menu inflation here.
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent openSettings = new Intent(activity, SettingsActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(openSettings);
                return true;
            case R.id.help:
                // others
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // do menu preparation here.
    }
}
```

Support composition in the base class (ie base class has a setter):

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Nullable
    private OptionsMenuHandler optionsMenuHandler;

    protected void setOptionsMenuHandler(OptionsMenuHandler optionsMenuHandler) {
        this.optionsMenuHandler = optionsMenuHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return optionsMenuHandler != null
               ? optionsMenuHandler.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
               : super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return optionsMenuHandler != null
               ? optionsMenuHandler.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
               : super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return optionsMenuHandler != null
               ? optionsMenuHandler.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
               : super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Set the implementation in the Activity that needs the functionality.

```
public class TestActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setOptionsMenuHandler(new DefaultOptionsMenuHandler(this));
    }
}
```

The net benefit here is that you write the main boilerplate once and support it through all of your activities.  You can also continue to keep your business logic defined in the top level activity - where it goes with the other various logic for that particular activity.

Most non-trivial apps would benefit from something along these lines.  I typically do something even more robust that supports zero or more OptionsMenuHandlers being set in any given activity where each handler supports a specific type of functionality.  The code for this is fairly long and many considerations are needed, so I won't produce it here.